# Can you connect to Oracle using WebMatrix?

Tags: oracle, webmatrix

I would like to use WebMatrix, but I work on a number of different database platforms, mainly Oracle and Sql Server.  If I cannot use Oracle, then WebMatrix is useless to me.

Has anyone made a WebMatrix app using Oracle as the back end?  What are the things to look out for?

Comment: Did searching for "oracle webmatrix" not answer at least part of your question?

Comment: No concrete examples or statements either way.  And since it was not obvious from an initial search, I feel that it's valuable to have this information on Stackoverflow for future askers.

Comment: have u tried using entity framework with it?  Googling I found: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/182/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Development-With-WebMatrix

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to anything that has an ADO.NET provider. WebMatrix is simply a tool for creating ASP.NET applications, so the entire .NET framework is available to you.